# Refreshing my DataTable model and view every few seconds

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm passing a DataTable to my view using models

`@model System.Data.DataTable`

I've made a simple table, and everything is working fine, the table is displayed.

`<table class="table" id="myTable"> 
... 
<table>`

But now I want to refresh the DataTable model and the <*table*>, without refreshing the whole page.

I've tried several javascript functions but I can't see anything related to a DataTable model or sucessful solutions.
Iam also worried about browser memory leak, after a few hours of refreshes.

I need help in the View and if that's the case, the additional controller code.

Thanks

Comment: [Datatables](https://www.datatables.net/) would work well in this scenario.  There's an example in the docs which uses [ajax.reload()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload%28%29)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you probably know, ASP runs on server. it means that the client needs to request from the server for the data and present it again. the easy way will be in JS to do `document.location.reload()` which is not user friendly.

You have javascript libraries that can help.

markpsmith suggestion is a great way to do it. But there is a learning curve.

Comment: I've had something in my controller. this.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("refresh", "20; url=" + Url.Action("Index")); Will take a look at marks's answer. Should I 'Accept' your answer or expect more answers?